# Proper attribution of derived work in a GPL project

Tags: licensing, gpl, attribution

This is a continuation of me [rewriting GPL project](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151515/rewrote-gnu-gpl-v2-code-in-another-language-can-i-change-a-license).

What will be the correct way of attributing my project as being a derivative of some other GPL-licensed project? So far I came up with:

```
HgSharp

Original Copyright Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com> and contributors.

The following code is a derivative work of the code from the Mercurial project, 
which is licensed GPLv2. This code therefore is also licensed under the terms 
of the GNU Public License, verison 2.                                                     

For information on the license of this code when distributed with and used 
in conjunction with the other modules in the HgSharp project, please see 
the root-level COPYING file.

Copyright 2011-2012 Anton Gogolev <anton.gogolev@hglabhq.com>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with after discussing and issue with Matt Mackall directly:

```
// HgSharp
// 
// Copyright 2005-2012 Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com> and Mercurial contributors
// Copyright 2011-2012 Anton Gogolev <anton.gogolev@hglabhq.com>
// 
// The following code is a derivative work of the code from the Mercurial project, 
// which is licensed GPLv2. This code therefore is also licensed under the terms 
// of the GNU Public License, verison 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. Perhaps you should also link to the homepage and source code of the original project.